How do I create photo grid with fixed height for each row?
I am currently struggling to create an image grid where each row has a set height and the image should use 100% of the width. All the images are 4:3 or 9:16. The thing I am trying to avoid is having any part of the photo overflow and be hidden. I am using next js 15.
An example of what I meant to describe can be seen on https://www.skylerknutzen.com/stills

I am using next js and this is my current code for the collage component and it's css:


import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from '@/components/collage.module.css';

const images = [
  { src: '/images/vertical1.jpg', alt: 'Vertical Image 1', orientation: 'vertical' },
  { src: '/images/horizontal1.jpg', alt: 'Horizontal Image 1', orientation: 'horizontal' },
  { src: '/images/vertical2.jpg', alt: 'Vertical Image 2', orientation: 'vertical' },
  { src: '/images/horizontal2.jpg', alt: 'Horizontal Image 2', orientation: 'horizontal' },
  { src: '/images/horizontal2.jpg', alt: 'Horizontal Image 2', orientation: 'horizontal' },
  { src: '/images/vertical2.jpg', alt: 'Vertical Image 2', orientation: 'vertical' },
  { src: '/images/vertical2.jpg', alt: 'Vertical Image 2', orientation: 'vertical' },
];

const Collage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.collageGrid}>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={`${styles.imageWrapper} ${image.orientation === 'vertical' ? styles.vertical : styles.horizontal}`}
        >
          <Image
            src={image.src}
            alt={image.alt}
            layout="responsive"
            width={1}
            height={1}
            className={styles.image}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Collage;
.collageGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 50px; /* Adjust as needed for even spacing */
    padding: 50px;
  }
  
  .imageWrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .vertical {
    grid-row: span 2; /* Vertical images span two rows */
  }
  
  .horizontal {
    height: 100%; /* Horizontal images fit within a single row */
  }
  
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }




Edit 1:
This is what I am envisioning:


Ah, yes I see, no worries, I've removed my comments as they no longer apply and encourage you to do the same. I'll also delete this one shortly.

As it stands the problem has no unique solution. For example in the image you show how was it decided that there should be one wide and one narrow image in the first row and three in the second row?

Hm, I see your point. I was honestly hoping for some sort of algorithmic way of determining a certain fixed height at which both images (Or however many you'd decide to put into one row) would align in such a way, a certain predefined width is reached (Including gaps between images). I am honestly not sure if what I am envisioning is possible or if I just made up some impossible idea though.

Ah, do you want the same fixed height on every row? How will that be specified (e.g. in vh units with some minimum?)

Yes I was thinking a fixed height (row specific) so the height changes on different rows but not in the same row. I tried a couple of thinks like using columns spans but that turned out to not work at all. My idea after that was really to just use px but vh units might actually be a better idea Edit: Im really open for anything

So if you want them to change on different rows, how is it decided what height you want on a particular row?

Well in the approach I thought of, I want to find a certain sweet spot between height and the width of all the images in the row combined. So what I mean is, let's say there's one 4:3 image and another 9:16 image in one row. As we increase or decrease the height of the row (Which both images are in) the width of the of the images would also change accordingly. So then there would be a certain height at which both images would have a width which perfectly fits a predefined width. That is what I mean. However I am not sure if I am making things more complicated then they need to be.

So the question remains, how is it decided what images go in the first row, which go in the second row etc? In the picture you have given with actual images, what was it that decided on one wide and one narrow in the first row and one wide and two narrow in the second row?  As things stand this question is not answered - it could just as easily be one image per row, or one wide and three narrow on the first row, or all of those 5 images on the first row etc.

Oh I understand. I don't know. I would say it was chosen manually though.

If you know how many wide and how many narrow images there are in a row and the overall width of a row and the fixed gap size then you can work out the row height. Is that what you are stuck on?

Yes exactly that

If W is the total width you want (e.g. 100vw) and G is the size of the inter image gap (e.g. 2vw) then the height of a row with L landscape( 4:3) images and P portrait (9:16) images is (W-(L+P)G)/((L4/3) + P*(9/16)) - assuming you want a half gap's worth at either end of the row. For ease of testing to see what looks good I'd write JS to do this with a simple array saying how many images in each row.
